# How to programatically add component via controller action in Ember 3.x

Tags: ember.js

I want to add add multiple copies of a component via js and pass different params in it. The code should execute via controller action of click on a button in the template. The solution for 2.x doesn't work in Ember version 3.x(pre-octane). Can anybody please help. I can't render plain html as I am using other addon of ember in the component.

Comment: Could you please share more context with us? It might be that the problem can be solved differently.

Answer (score 1):

Basically you want an array with the params in the js, and then a `{{#each` loop invoking the components. Something like this:

```js
@tracked componentParams = new TrackedArray();

@action showThem() {
  this.componentParams.push({ value="foo" });
  this.componentParams.push({ value="bar" });
  this.componentParams.push({ value="baz" });
}
```

```
{{#each this.componentParams as |params|}}
  <MyComponent @value={{params.value}} />
{{/each}}
<button type="button" {{on "click" this.showThem}}>Show Them</button>
```

(this uses `TrackedArray` from [`tracked-built-ins`](https://github.com/pzuraq/tracked-built-ins)).